# How to get range of OnData indexes from Virtual Listview

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, tlistview

I'm dealing with large text files (bigger than 100MB). I'm using a TListView (OwnerData=True). ListView's OnData event gives me required items one by one.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption:=MyStringList.strings[Item.Index];
end;
```

But I need the full range of required items at once (after scrolling). I need this conceptual event:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1DataRange(Sender: TObject; ItemIndexStarts: int64; ItemIndexEnds: int64);
begin
  LoadMyItemsByRange(ItemIndexStarts,ItemIndexEnds);
end;
```

LoadMyItemsByRange is easy to implement. How can I get ItemIndexStarts and ItemIndexEnds values? Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnData` event is for returning data for a *specific* item only, there is no range provided.  You are correct to use the `Item.Index` property to know which item is being requested.

If you want to pre-load your data ahead of time, you need to use the `OnDataHint` event, in addition to the `OnData` event.  The `OnDataHint` event gives you a range of indexes that are the ListView's best guess to which item(s) are *likely* to be needed soon, due to scrolling, drawing, etc.

However, that being said, there is no *guarantee* that the `OnData` event will ask only for items that were previously requested by the `OnDataHint` event.  That is why it is called a *hint*.  Your `OnData` handler needs to be prepared to load items that have not been loaded yet.  And, for good measure, it is a good idea to have the first few items and the last few items always loaded at all times if possible, as the ListView refers to those items fairly often.

Comment: Whoever created OnDataHint was a real wise guy.

Comment: That would be Microsoft. `OnData` is a wrapper for the [`LVN_GETDISPINFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-getdispinfo) notification, and `OnDataHint` for [`LVN_ODCACHEHINT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-odcachehint) notification. See [Virtual List-View Style](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style) for more details, especially the section on [Cache Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#cache-management).